# Joomla JS file Remove on after question mark data

Tags: php, joomla

How to JS file Remove on after question mark data?

/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js?74a9f5d23561aa584c363ede5bfbfad6

For Example - Only load on /media/jui/js/jquery.min.js

Comment: It is REALLY not clear what you are actually asking here!

Comment: @RiggsFolly sounds to me like they want to disable a cache buster?

Comment: @CBroe That sounds feasable

Comment: @RiggsFolly How to Remove on jquery? "?74a9f5d23561aa584c363ede5bfbfad6"

Comment: If this was a simple string manipulation, there are thousands of Stack Overflow volunteers who can do this in php.  However, I'll bet that you have more specific requirements that would benefit from the insights of volunteers who have an intimate understanding of Joomla.  I recommend that you post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

The alpha numeric `?74a9f5d23561aa584c363ede5bfbfad6` string you speak of is added by code within Joomla. Its appended to the url.

Something like this for example

```
<?php
JHtml::_('script', 'media/jui/js/jquery.min.js', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true));
?>
```

More details in the Joomla docs

https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript/en